# Laravel custom schedule logs

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is simple, I would like to custom the format of the string that is written in my schedule.log by the laravel scheduler

Example, in my schedule.log, logs are like this:

`No scheduled commands are ready to run.`

I would like it to be like this:

`[2020-12-22 10:24:52] INFO: No scheduled commands are ready to run.`

Do you have any idea how I can do it ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Check out the logging documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging

Answer (score 0):

In `config/logging.php` set a new log channel within 'channels' array:

```
'schedule' => [
   'driver' => 'single',
   'path' => storage_path('logs/schedule.log'),
],
```

Then when you write your log, refer to the channel:

```
Log::channel('schedule')->info('No scheduled commands are ready to run.');
```

Comment: Sorry I remove the `Log` part because the laravel scheduler writes directly into a specific file (shedule.log for me). So the question is how to custom the writing of the scheduler log to be like the example `[2020-12-22 10:24:52] INFO: No scheduled commands are ready to run.` ? TY

Comment: Updated the answer to allow logging to a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

this automatically does the format of what you are looking for, as laravel handles the date for you.

```php
Log::info("TEXT HERE");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal shell output and you could log with it what you execute the command with.

Otherwise you can log the events directly:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#events